# Trouble inserting string variable as attribute value of new element

Tags: xml, string, vb.net, variables, element

In Vb.Net , I am having trouble inserting string variable as attribute value of new element!
I cannot insert the variable CGID_Param inside value of CaptionID attribute of the element, because with every method i tried it is recognized as simple text

```
Private Sub MyMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyMenuItem.Click
    
            Dim result As DialogResult = OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
            Dim path = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
            Dim _xdoc As New XDocument()
            _xdoc = XDocument.Load(path)
    
            Dim CGID_Param As String = System.Guid.NewGuid.ToString()

            _xdoc.Root.Element("ParamsNode").Add(
             <Param ID="BatchID" CaptionID=""" & CGID_Param & """ Visible="False" MultiSelect="False">
                    </Param>)

            _xdoc.Save(path)

        End Sub
```

I Have tried

```
<Param ID="BatchID" CaptionID=""" & CGID_Param & """ Visible="False" MultiSelect="False">
```

or

```
<Param ID="BatchID" CaptionID="%=CGID_Param%"  Visible="False" MultiSelect="False">
```

But it keeps recognizing it as simple text .

Comment: _xdoc.Root.Element("ParamsNode").Add(New XElement("Param ID", New Object() {New XAttribute("CaptionID", "CGID_Param"), New XAttribute("Visible", "False"), New XAttribute("MultiSelect", "False"), "BatchID"}))

Comment: @jdweng thank you for the reply , but  putting CGID_Param just in double quotes is still recongnized as text and not a variable .

Comment: XML is text.  There are not parameters.